# Ubuntu 12.04 Server install fails, loops to restart

Tags: 12.04, installation, server, restart

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 12.04.2 Server 64bit on an Intel Core 2 Duo PC (2GB RAM).

I can boot from CD or USB-Stick (tried both) and the menu where I can choose to install Ubuntu server appears. However, after I have chosen this and have pressed enter, the computer just restarts and I'm back inside the menu (well, that's like in "Groundhog Day").

I have already installed Ubuntu on a couple of PCs, but this is the first time I encounter this problem and I haven't found a solution anywhere on the web.

I have checked md5-sums of the installer image. I have downloaded the image again, tried the 32bit version, tried via usb, via two different CDs, checked the BIOS (but nothing there that's obviously wrong) -- always I remain in that restart loop.
This also happens when I choose any other option from the menu (check RAM etc).
Remark: I have found out that the PC has an Intel Board DG33FB.

The existing Windows XP however runs without problems. I just want to delete everything and install Ubuntu server on it. (Do I have to erase the disk manually first?)

Does anybody know what to do/Has somebody solved a similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

what about using the alternate installer? I've had unexplained issues before and the alt seems to work better.

http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04.2-alternate-amd64.iso.torrent

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I used a Lubuntu-ISO now, as I need an XServer anyway --
and this just worked fine without any problems.

I just do not know nor understand why the Ubuntu-Server ISO did not work.